# Exporting data of 7 columns from listbox into worksheet into selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I transfer data of 7 columns from listbox into a worksheet, into selected cells (A20:G29). The data transfer into the next available cells, not into A20:G29

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim addme As Range
    Dim x As Integer

    Set addme = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    For x = 0 To Me.lstSelector.ListCount - 1
        If Me.lstSelector.Selected(x) Then
            addme = Me.lstSelector.List(x)
            addme.Offset(0, 1) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 1)
            addme.Offset(0, 2) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 2)
            addme.Offset(0, 3) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 3)
            addme.Offset(0, 4) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 4)
            addme.Offset(0, 5) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 5)
            addme.Offset(0, 6) = Me.lstSelector.List(x, 6)
            Set addme = addme.Offset(1, 0)
         End If
    Next x

    For x = 0 To Me.lstSelector.ListCount - 1
     If Me.lstSelector.Selected(x) Then Me.lstSelector.Selected(x) = False
    Next x

End Sub

Private Sub cmdclose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub lstSelector_Click()

End Sub
```

I need suggestions

Comment: Yes. Why do you think that is?

Comment: Thank you so much David. In deed you are the BOMB! You made my day. It's working 100%.

Answer (score 0):

This line establishes the starting range/cell for where the data will be output:

```
Set addme = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

It is a relatively crude but often used way of finding the last cell in a range.  So, this makes sense that your procedure will always "transfer into the next available cells", and not in to some other specific range of cells.

Try this instead:

```
Set addme = Sheet2.Range("A20")
```